# how do I show all rows from 5 tables except one for mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically I want to show all rows from all my 5 tables except one.

Below are the relations

- A connected to B
- B connected with C
- C connected with D
- B connected with E

I want to have rows from all tables except E based on relations I mention

so my approach is

```
    select some fields
    from 
    ( SELECT 5 AS dummy_id) AS dummy_table
    right outer join B on dummy_table.dummy_id=B.some_id
    right outer join A on A.some_id=B.some_id
    right outer join C on C.some_id=B.some_id
    inner join E on E.some_id=B.some_id
    right outer join D on C.some_id=D.some_id
```

my guess is since when we specify right outer join before a table name.

eg

```
right outer join D
```

That implies I am selecting all rows from that tables.

But here I insert a dummy table to extract all rows for my very first table.

Just wanted to confirm Is my approach correct,Since I want to avoid the key word full outer join and union as its known mysql doesn't support full outer join

Comment: . . It would really help if you provided some sample data and expected results.  Your interpretation of right outer join is correct, although I think most people would start with a table do a left outer join.  If you want to combine the rows, then consider `union all`.

Comment: As you haven't supplied any sample data, DB schema, or desired output, it's pretty difficult to provide a lot of help. What happens when you try this yourself? Does it work? If it doesn't, in what way does it fail?

Comment: @GordonLinoff for some reason I don't wont to use left outer join or union.
So I felt even for two tables why not add a dummy table at the start and right outer join instead of the conventional left outer join

Comment: @KenWhite the sql works grabs the results but for some reason I wanted to see are there any flaws in my logic.